# Django overwrite model save method to check if a many to many field has changed

Tags: python, django, model

so I have a model for which I need to overwrite the save property to check if a many to many relation has changed. Normally for like a char field you could do something like the below, but for many to many it works differently.

```
class Interest(TimestampedModel):
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField('genre.Subject', blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.id:
            old_subjects = Interest.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).first().subjects.all()
            subjects = self.subjects.all()
            if subjects != old_subjects:
                # Do stuff
```

Any idea how to make something like this for a many to many field?

Answer (score 1):

How about a signal? Checkout the `m2m_changed` signal docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/).

You can use it like:

```
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed

@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Interest.subjects.through)
def video_category_changed(sender, instance, **kwargs):

    # do stuff to the Interest instance:
    instance...
```

Comment: That is helpful, it does give me a nice start, but it's not quite the answer I am looking for. My bad for not being descriptive enough. How would one expand this to check the "old_subjects" and the "new_subjects" variables like in my example.

I need to have access to both the old subjects and new subjects after m2m changed for the action I want to perform.

Comment: There are the `pre_add`, `post_add`, `pre_remove`, and `post_remove` kwargs - I have not used them before but, per the docs, it appears you can use these to solve your problem.